# Website - nearly same clients, different informations

Tags: php, javascript, client, html

There are two (or more) computers on LAN with internet access.

They have the same:

operating system,

browser and browser version,

user name.

They are visiting my webpage which can use js and php to retrive informations.

Is there any way I can find differences between these clients with retrived information?
Which informations are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a (random valued) cookie or a session.

The two machines will have unique identities.

Answer (score 0):

Their IP addresses would be different, unless they're using a proxy and/or NAT firewall. That information can be retrieved trivially via `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. There *may* an `X-Forwarded-For` header that some proxies might put in place, revealing the internal address, but it's not guaranteed to be there, and definitely not guaranteed to be reliable.

There's a few client-side tricks you can use to get machine's local address, but again, if they're behind a NAT firewall and/or proxy, there's no guaranteed that both machines aren't on two seperate networks and both coincidentally have the same private IP address.